# How to git fetch using gitpython?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am looking for a equivalent way to fetch in gitpython

```
git fetch --quiet --all
```

How can I perform git fetch in python?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The [`fetch` method](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=Fetch#module-git.remote) is equivalent to issuing `git fetch`. Accordingly, you can fetch all your remotes by iterating and fetching each individually:

```
repo = git.Repo('name_of_repo')
for remote in repo.remotes:
    remote.fetch()
```

Comment: Also, ```repo.remotes.origin.fetch()```